# Cannot convert from 'char' to 'myClass *'

Tags: c++, pointers, linked-list, char, derived-class

all. I am trying to write a linked list of pointer objects. Upon changing    obj    to    obj*    , the compiler began to complain about my initializer constructors, claiming:

```
a)    Error C2078: too many initializers

b)    Error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'char' to 'myClass *'
```

My calls to initializer constructors contain the same amount of parameters as is defined in my initializer constructors. I'm also not sure how to interpret b. Here is a snippet of my code:

```
myClass * obj('a', 0.0, 1, 1, 1, 1, "string", "string", "string");
```

Here is my function declaration:

```
myClass * obj(char *val1, double val2, int val3, int val4, long long val4, long long val5, string val6, string val7, string val8).
```

Any words of advice? I wasn't even sure what code to include. Let me know if I can include anything to make this clearer. Thanks!

P.S. I am new to posting, hence why I could not format some text in here properly.

Answer (score 2):

You can't initialize a pointer with a long list of arguments.

---

Perhaps irrelevant or ungood guess, but did you mean to call a function named `obj`, that returns a pointer, and that takes a pointer to modifiable C string as first argument?

In that case, consider e.g.

```
char s[] = "a";
myClass* p = obj(s, 0.0, 1, 1, 1, 1, "string", "string", "string");
```

Answer (score 0):

This

```
myClass * obj(char *val1
```

won't accept

```
'a'
```

but will happily accept

```
"a"
```

NOTE:: You should not attempt to change content of val1 in this function.

Error::cannot convert from 'char' to 'myClass *' means

you are returning char from this function where you should return pointer to myclass object.In that case also you should prohibit yourself from returning address of local object ( object allocated on stack).

Comment: Would require a `const char *` to accept `"a"` happily (i.e. without using deprecated conversions)

Comment: So you meant to say [char *str = "abcd"] is not correct...as far as you are not changing content of this.

Comment: It will generate a warning indeed. (clang: "warning: ISO C++11 does not allow conversion from string literal to 'char *'")